# Postgres SQL default value on left join is NULL

Tags: postgresql, left-join

Query:

```
select t1.*,
       t2.businesstype as business_type
from business t1
LEFT JOIN businesstype t2 ON t1.business_id = t2.business_id
```

I would like to have a default value 'NA' incase if the left join return null (t2.businesstype as business_type). The query should return business_type = 'NA' if its Null.

Any help is greatly appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `coalesce`. This will pick first non-null value:

```
select t1.*,
       coalesce(t2.businesstype, 'NA') as business_type
from business t1
LEFT JOIN businesstype t2 ON t1.business_id = t2.business_id
```